# Decode Base_64 in Python (AWS)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, base64

I have a React front end (in which I am submitting files) via FormData as follows:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('username', 'USER123');
data.append('file', selectedFile);
await fetch('https://myapigatewayURL/test', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
  body:data
}).then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json))
```

From there, I want to receive the file and receive the username. I realize that FormData will be sending in a base64 encoded body request and so in my Lambda Python function (integrated with my API route), I used:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(base64.b64decode(event['body']))
```

Now, this prints out a weird string:

```
b'------WebKitFormBoundaryTcc1zTIsK4TCH7lY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="username"\r\n\r\nUSER123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryTcc1zTIsK4TCH7lY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="bootstrap.sh"\r\nContent-Type: text/x-sh\r\n\r\n#!/bin/sh\nset -e\n\n# add container metadata to index.html\necho "<pre>" >> /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html\ncurl $ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI | jq \'.\' >> /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html\necho "</pre>" >> /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html\n\n# run httpd\nhttpd-foreground\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryTcc1zTIsK4TCH7lY--\r\n'
```

How am I supposed to receive my file and username from this string?

Described what I tried in question